# UseRouting() and useEndPoints() in asp.net core web api aren't present

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm curious about the absence of useRouting and useEndpoints in .NET 6, especially considering that they were available in .NET 5. I've noticed that there have been changes where the program.cs and startup.cs files have been merged. Could you please clarify how the routing configuration works in this new structure? Thank you in advance for your help!
here is the program.cs file

`

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using WebApplication1.Data;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(name : "SuperHeroOrigins",
    policy => {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        }
    
    ));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("SuperHeroOrigins");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

i wanna clarification about the updates from .net5 to .net6

Answer (score 0):

Routing uses a pair of middleware, registered by `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`:

`UseRouting` adds route matching to the middleware pipeline. This middleware looks at the set of endpoints defined in the app, and selects the best match based on the request.
`UseEndpoints` adds endpoint execution to the middleware pipeline. It runs the delegate associated with the selected endpoint.The `MapGet` method is used to define an endpoint, like: `MapControllers` for controllers.

**In  .net5**  **:**

Routing is registered in the middleware pipeline in Startup.Configure. like:

```
 app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    });
```

**In net6:**

Apps typically don't need to call UseRouting or UseEndpoints. WebApplicationBuilder configures a middleware pipeline that wraps middleware added in Program.cs with UseRouting and UseEndpoints

You can read [Routing basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#routing-basics-1) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

use `[Route("products/{productId}")]` dataanotation for routing configuration at action level